# Splitting a table into multiple tables in Power BI

Tags: oracle, powerbi

I have this following data in a single table. I need to split this table into multiple tables based on the YearMonth Column. Is there a way to automate this task.

```
 +------------+-----------+
| Year_Month |   Part#   |
+------------+-----------+
| 2014-03    | CCH057169 |
| 2014-03    | CCH057276 |
| 2014-03    | CCH057303 |
| 2014-03    | CCH057430 |
| 2014-04    | CCH057409 |
| 2014-04    | CCH057497 |
| 2014-04    | CCH057570 |
| 2014-04    | CCH057583 |
| 2014-04    | CCH057650 |
| 2014-04    | CCH057696 |
| 2014-04    | CCH057707 |
| 2014-04    | CCH057798 |
| 2014-05    | CCH057701 |
| 2014-06    | CCH057235 |
| 2014-06    | CCH057280 |
| 2014-06    | CCH057693 |
| 2014-06    | CCH057707 |
| 2014-06    | CCH057721 |
| 2014-07    | CCH057235 |
| 2014-07    | CCH057427 |
| 2014-08    | CCH057650 |
| 2014-08    | CCH057696 |
| 2014-08    | CCH057798 |
| 2014-09    | CCH057303 |
| 2014-09    | CCH057482 |
| 2014-09    | CCH057668 |
| 2014-09    | CCH057744 |
| 2014-09    | CCH057776 |
| 2014-10    | CCH057668 |
| 2014-10    | CCH057696 |
| 2014-11    | CCH057390 |
| 2014-11    | CCH057409 |
| 2014-11    | CCH057679 |
| 2014-11    | CCH057700 |
| 2014-11    | CCH057721 |
| 2014-11    | CCH057749 |
| 2014-11    | CCH057896 |
| 2014-12    | CCH057169 |
| 2014-12    | CCH057693 |
| 2014-12    | CCH057696 |
| 2014-12    | CCH057708 |
| 2014-12    | CCH057876 |
| 2014-12    | CCH057896 |
| 2015-01    | CCH057630 |
| 2015-01    | CCH057679 |
| 2015-01    | CCH057700 |
| 2015-01    | CCH057776 |
| 2015-02    | CCH057409 |
| 2015-02    | CCH057482 |
+------------+-----------+
```

More Information:

I am getting the data from Oracle Database. The Purpose of this data is to compare between two given Dates and provide new records. Is there a way that I select two dates on the form (Slicer) and then the query has to fetch the data based on the date selection on the form.

Comment: Look at the BETWEEN operator in Oracle help. There are tons of resources and examples. All you need is to select your data between two dates. Use TO_DATE() function if you need to. Not sure what is your year-month data format. Look here for the example of between two dates: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/between.php

Answer (score 0):

Might be splitting hairs, but from a database (RDBMS) perspective, slicers change what is summarized and displayed, not what is queried. So, you might want to take some steps so you don't do something like getting the introduction date of every product Amazon has ever offered.

It sounds like you want to use a slicer with a range slider, which only works on numbers and dates. So, first add a column computed from the Year_Month column for a date, say the end of the month, and call it Month.

```
Month = EOMONTH(DATEVALUE([Year_Month] & "-01"), 0)
```

Then all you need to do is create a grid with the part# field and create a slicer for the Month field, which is initially configured with a range slider.